# Python Write Personal User ID using RC522

Tags: python-3.4, mifare

I'm struggling in using Python3 for writing and reading personal user id in rc522. Here I want to write (for example, 123) in the rfid based on the input. However, after I write '123', the python says

> can't concat list to bytearray.

Please, help. Thank you :D

```
info = input("Personal ID")
info = int(info)
status = MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Auth(MIFAREReader.PICC_AUTHENT1A,8,key,uid)

if status == MIFAREReader.MI_OK:
     data = bytearray(16)
     value = format(info,'x')
     while (8 > len(value)):
           value = '0' + value
     data[0:8] = bytearray.fromhex(value)

MIFAREReader.MFRC522_Write(8,data)


def (self,blockAddr,writeData)
    buff = []
    buff.append(self.PICC_WRITE)
    buff.append(blockAddr)
    crc = self.CalulateCRC(buff)
    buff += crc
    (status,backData,backLen) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(
        self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE,buff
    )

    buff = writeData[0:8]
    crc = self.CalulateCRC(buff)
    buff += crc     /////the error is pointed here
    (status,backData,backLen) = self.MFRC522_ToCard(
        self.PCD_TRANSCEIVE,buff
    )

    if status == self.MI_OK:
        return True
```

Comment: Hi Dominic and welcome to SO! Your question is a bit unclear as in which line the error occurs. There are also some syntax errors (`self.MFRC522_ToCard(sekf.PCD_TRANSCEIVE,buff` is missing it's closing parenthesis isn't it?).

Comment: @FlorianBlume thanks for noticing my error. I already edited.